# React hook api state is sometimes empty

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am using hook api for managing state, the problem is that state is sometimes empty in handler fucntion.

I am using component for manage `contenteditable` (using from npm) lib. You can write to component and on enter you can send event to parent.

See my example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import css from './text-area.scss'
import ContentEditable from 'react-contenteditable'
import { safeSanitaze } from './text-area-utils'

type Props = {
    onSubmit: (value: string) => void,
}

const TextArea = ({ onSubmit }: Props) => {
    const [isFocused, setFocused] = useState(false);
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')

    const handleChange = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
        const newValue = event?.currentTarget?.textContent || '';
        setValue(safeSanitaze(newValue))
    }

    const handleKeyPress = (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
        // enter
        const code = event.which || event.keyCode
        if (code === 13) {
            console.log(value) // THERE IS A PROBLEM, VALUE IS SOMETIMES EMPTY, BUT I AM SURE THAT TEXT IS THERE!!!
            onSubmit(safeSanitaze(event.currentTarget.innerHTML))
            setValue('')
        }
    }

    const showPlaceHolder = !isFocused && value.length === 0

    const cls = [css.textArea]
    if (!isFocused) cls.push(css.notFocused)

    console.log(value) // value is not empty

    return (
        <ContentEditable
            html={showPlaceHolder ? 'Join the discussion…' : value}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className={cls.join(' ')}
            onClick={() => setFocused(true)}
            onBlur={() => setFocused(false)}
            onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
        />
    )
}

export default React.memo(TextArea)
```

Main problem is that inside `handleKeyPress` (after enter keypress) is `value` (from state) empty string, why? - in block `console.log(value) // THERE IS A PROBLEM, VALUE IS SOMETIMES EMPTY, BUT I AM SURE THAT TEXT IS THERE!!!` I don't understand what is wrong??

Answer (score 0):

The value is empty, because `onChange` doesn't actually change it, which means

`const newValue = event?.currentTarget?.textContent || '';`

this line doesn't do what it's supposed to. I think you should read the `target` prop in react's synthetic events instead of `currentTarget`. So, try this instead

`const newValue = event.target?.value || '';`

Hope this helps.